# How to apply K fold cross validation on regression type of target variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, data-science

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy

#Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss="mean_squared_error")
    return model

seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
print(results.mean())
```

**AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'loss'**

> I am getting an error as the loss does not belong to kerasClassifier
>   and I tried KerasRegressor also still same error I am getting.solve my
>   issue.

Answer (score 0):

In create_model() function you should return 'classifier', not a global 'model' variable.

Comment: Is this error the same as 'AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'loss''? If you have different error, you can accept this answer and ask another question with new error at SO.

Answer (score 0):

The model is not configured to compute accuracy. You should pass metrics=["accuracy"] to the model.compile() method:

```
 def create_model():
     classifier = Sequential()
     classifier.add(Dense(12, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
     classifier.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
     classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
     classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])
     return classifier  #model

  model=KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
  results=cross_val_score(model,titanic1[predictors],titanic1['Survived'],cv=kfold)
  print(results.mean())
  >>> 0.6770466277619704
```